# DeviceIoControl with IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS - C#

Tags: c#, winapi

I've C++ code that calls DeviceIoControl with IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS that I need to convert to C#.
I've found many DeviceIoControl p\invoke samples, but none for this specific flag.
I've tried using the following extern:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool DeviceIoControl(SafeFileHandle hVol, int controlCode, IntPtr inBuffer, int inBufferSize, ref DiskExtents outBuffer, int outBufferSize, ref int bytesReturned, IntPtr overlapped);
```

structures:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DiskExtent
{
    public uint DiskNumber;
    public long StartingOffset;
    public long ExtentLength;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DiskExtents
{
    public int numberOfExtents;
    public DiskExtent[] first;
}
```

And the following calling code:

```
int bytesReturned = 0;
DiskExtents diskExtents = new DiskExtents();
bool res = DeviceIoControl(hVol, 5636096, IntPtr.Zero, 0, ref diskExtents, Marshal.SizeOf(diskExtents), ref bytesReturned, IntPtr.Zero);
```

But the call return false and the data structure is always empty.
Any help would be great!

Comment: How many disks do you need this to work with? It'll be *significantly* easier to call it to fill in just one DiskExtent structure. Do you need to support more than one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that an array cannot be marshalled unless its size is known. This means that your `DiskExtents` structure cannot be marshalled properly when making the `DeviceIoControl` call.

The following code works for me (I tend to prefer explicitly-sized types for interop purposes, and prefer to stick with the names from the Win32 headers since I already know what they mean and can Google them easily):

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
   internal const UInt32 IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS = 0x00560000;

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   internal class DISK_EXTENT
   {
      public UInt32 DiskNumber;
      public Int64  StartingOffset;
      public Int64  ExtentLength;
   }

   [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
   internal class VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS
   {
      public UInt32      NumberOfDiskExtents;
      public DISK_EXTENT Extents;
   }

   [DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]                             
   internal static extern bool DeviceIoControl(SafeFileHandle hDevice,
                                               UInt32         ioControlCode,
                                               IntPtr         inBuffer,
                                               UInt32         inBufferSize,
                                               IntPtr         outBuffer,
                                               UInt32         outBufferSize,
                                               out UInt32     bytesReturned,
                                               IntPtr         overlapped);
}
```

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       // Open the volume handle using CreateFile()
       SafeFileHandle sfh = ...

       // Prepare to obtain disk extents.
       // NOTE: This code assumes you only have one disk!
       NativeMethods.VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS vde           = new NativeMethods.VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS();
       UInt32                            outBufferSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(vde);
       IntPtr                            outBuffer     = Marshal.AllocHGlobal((int)outBufferSize);
       UInt32                            bytesReturned = 0;
       if (NativeMethods.DeviceIoControl(sfh,
                                         NativeMethods.IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,
                                         IntPtr.Zero,
                                         0,
                                         outBuffer,
                                         outBufferSize,
                                         out bytesReturned,
                                         IntPtr.Zero))
       {
          // The call succeeded, so marshal the data back to a
          // form usable from managed code.
          Marshal.PtrToStructure(outBuffer, vde);

          // Do something with vde.Extents here...e.g.
          Console.WriteLine("DiskNumber: {0}\nStartingOffset: {1}\nExtentLength: {2}",
                            vde.Extents.DiskNumber,
                            vde.Extents.StartingOffset,
                            vde.Extents.ExtentLength);
       }
       Marshal.FreeHGlobal(outBuffer);
    }
}
```

Of course, this assumes that you only need to obtain information about a single disk. If you need the `DeviceIoControl` function to fill in the `VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS` structure with information about *multiple* disks, you will have to work harder.

The problem is that you won't know until run-time exactly how many disks there are. `DeviceIoControl` will return `ERROR_MORE_DATA` to inform you that there is more information left on the table and that you need to call again with a larger buffer. You'll do that along the same lines as above, with a number of extra complications. You will need to use something like `Marshal.ReAllocHGlobal` to expand the size of the buffer to accommodate the additional `DISK_EXTENT` structures. The required number will be returned in the `VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS.NumberOfDiskExtents` member after the first unsuccessful call to `DeviceIoControl`. [This C# code](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/citrix/xenserver/win/xenguestagent/src/xenguestlib/Win32Impl.cs) shows a similar implementation.

The time spent writing nasty code like this is why I have largely given up developing Windows apps in C#. It creates the inescapable paradox where C++ would have been cleaner, more elegant, easier to write, and *less error prone*. (Are you certain that I didn't leak any handles in the above code? I'm not.)